# Attaching Excel File in Email

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am attempting to fix an issue with a VBA for attaching a file from Excel directly into email with a .Display before user sends. The file should save, create a new temp file, copy and paste that temp file directly into the body of the email, while attaching the actual original document to the email for reference. Once this is done, it should kill the temp file without saving it.

The issue I'm having is that it will create the new temp workbook, but not copy and paste info into email or attach the document in the email. My code is below with the stock email address. Any Help is appreciated. The error message always seems to fall on `.Attachments.Add (ActiveDocument.FullName)`

```
Sub SendEmailOutlook()
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    'Send an email. basically just to standardize and error-proof the process
    'RangetoHTML function (below this macro) allows a range of cells to be pasted into the email body    
    Dim strbody As String    
    Dim rng As Range    
    Dim OutApp As Object    
    Dim OutMail As Object    
    Dim Message As String    
    Dim subject As String    
    Dim UpdateTime As String        

    'this line is extra for HTML formatting but it makes the text easier to read    
    strbody = "<P STYLE='font-family:Calibri;font-size:12pt'>"

    subject = "2018 Safety Walk Form for " & Sheets("2018 Safety Walk").Range("H5") & " " & Sheets("2018 Safety Walk").Range("K5")

    Message = "Team <br><br>Please see the attached form for, " & Sheets("2018 Safety Walk").Range("K5")

    'Set last row based on input data
    '    Dim lastRow As String    
    '    lastRow = Sheets("Email").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'Set range for email body    
    'The column is on the right, the row on the left. Change to .Range("A1:H30") if you want it to be static

    Set rng = Sheets("2018 Safety Walk").Range("B5:K43")

    'Create email
    With Application    
        .EnableEvents = False    
        .ScreenUpdating = False    
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")    
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail    
        .To = "123@123.com"    
        .BCC = ""    
        .subject = subject    
        .HTMLBody = strbody & Message & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>"    
        .Attachments.Add (ActiveDocument.FullName)        
        .Display    'you can use .Send to have the macro send the email without needing to confirm it    
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application    
        .EnableEvents = True    
        .ScreenUpdating = True    
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing    
    Set OutApp = Nothing    
End Sub




Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)    
    Dim fso As Object    
    Dim ts As Object    
    Dim TempFile As String    
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in    
    rng.Copy    
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)

    With TempWB.Sheets(1)    
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8    
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False    
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False    
        .Cells(1).Select    
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        On Error Resume Next    
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True    
        .DrawingObjects.Delete   
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With         

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: It would help to know what the exact error message you are getting is. That said... Where is `ActiveDocument` coming from? That's a Word object, not an Excel object. Try using `ActiveWorkbook` instead.

Comment: Hey Patrick, I've also attempted to use ActiveWorkbook - same result. Error message received when running macro "Run-time error '424': Object Required". Once I go into the macro, the .Attachment.Add (ActiveWorkbook.FullName) is what is highlighted yellow (changed it back to workbook instead of document. Upon running the macro, error message received is, "run-time error '-2147024894 (80070002)': Cannot find this file. Verify the Path and file name are correct." It should be pulling information from temp file to copy / paste cells into the body of the email but attaching the original document.

Answer (score 1):

From the OP's comment:

> Upon running the macro, error message received is, "run-time error
>   '-2147024894 (80070002)': Cannot find this file. Verify the Path and
>   file name are correct."

This is because in your `RangeToHTML` function you are creating *two* temporary workbooks but only closing one. So once `RangeToHTML` returns, your `ActiveWorkbook` is referring to the remaining temporary workbook and not to your original. Since it has not been saved, its `.FullName` property does not yet have a value, so thus the "Cannot find this file" error.

In `RangeToHTML`, get rid of one of these sections where you copy/paste and your problem will be solved:

```
'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in    
rng.Copy    
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)

With TempWB.Sheets(1)    
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8    
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False    
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False    
    .Cells(1).Select    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    On Error Resume Next    
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True    
    .DrawingObjects.Delete   
    On Error GoTo 0
End With         

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

You should also, in your `SendEmailOutlook` procedure, not use `ActiveWorkbook` at all, since as you can see this will trip you up if you aren't careful. It's always better to set and work with a reference directly to the workbook.

So, something like:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Your Workbook Name")
```

or:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
```

at the start of `SendEmailOutlook`, and then use `wb` wherever you currently use `ActiveWorkbook` elsewhere in the procedure.